# spark trying to convert .Mf4 to save as .txt files, getting issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, asammdf

I have a spark code which reads .mf4 files and write as a .txt file. Also running this code in databricks.

Could you please suggest? Even after increasing the executor memory in data bricks in cluster, still having the issue.

```
pip install asammdf

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from asammdf import MDF
import io
import os
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import col



os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("mdf4") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

def decodeBinary(val):
    file_stream = io.BytesIO(val)
    mdf = MDF(file_stream)
    location = mdf.whereis(test_1)
    return location
print("1")
input_hdfs_path_to_mdf4 = "dbfs:/FileStore/inputmfd4/"
channel_name = "test_1"
local_or_hdfs_output_path = "dbfs:/FileStore/outputmfd4/opp4.txt"
print("2")
raw_binary = sc.binaryFiles(input_hdfs_path_to_mdf4)
print("3")
decoded_binary = raw_binary.map(lambda r: r[1]).map(decodeBinary)
print("4")
decoded_binary.saveAsTextFile(local_or_hdfs_output_path)
print("5")
print(decoded_binary)
```

I am running this code in databricks , I have 5Gb mf4 file as a input. When I try to run small file there is no issue. But when I use this 5GB mf4 file getting

```
Caused by org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: asammdf.blocks.utils.MdfException: <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7efed84482c0> is not a valid ASAM MDF file: magic header is b\xff\xd8\xff\xe1H\xe6Ex from command-2705692180399242 line 24 Full traceback below
Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the first 100 bytes from the file? It is most likely not a valid MDF file

Edit: see [iPhone JPG image has non-standard magic bytes ff d8 ff e1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975172/iphone-jpg-image-has-non-standard-magic-bytes-ff-d8-ff-e1)

Comment: ok sure, Is there anyway that write the binary data frame to text ? Via spark